# Adding data into mysql database using Angularjs and ionic framework

Tags: mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework. In my app, i am trying to input something and when the user hits the add button i want it to save in my database. How do i define the controller for that? And what backend should i use for routing here? I am really confused here where to start. Please help me out. Any lead will be helpful. Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-header-bar class="top">
      <h1 class="Title">Ionic App</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      Add URL: <input>
      <button>Add</button>
    </ion-content>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you need any other html pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some receipes to get you started:

1. create a view with form elements backed by a controller that holds an initial (model) value for every element.
2. get familiar with "2-Way-Data-Binding" using the [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive. This basically *connects* your form elements with the model values.
3. in the controller create a function that for example saves your model to a DB (something like `$scope.saveData(){...};`)
4. add the [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive to your "save" button: `<button ng-click"saveData()">Add</button>` to call the function.
5. Have a look at [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) or [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) and learn about RESTful Webservices to connect to your backend.
6. Implement a REST endpoint on your server that saves the data to the DB
7. See [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/) for a tutorial that will take you further. There are plenty of such tutorials on the web.

Good luck! :-)